# Using MyXQL with Phoenix - Can't connect to database

Tags: mysql, sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I am using the `MyXQL` driver with Ecto in Phoenix, and am trying to connect to an *already existing* MySQL database running on a Debian 11 server.

I can access the server normally using `mysql -p`, and can access it through Express (which is what I was using before I started migrating to Phoenix / Elixir).

When I try to run:

```
{ :ok, pid } = MyXQL.start_link([ username: "{username}", password: "{password}" ])
```

I get an error that reads:

`[error] MyXQL.Connection (#PID<0.449.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) (/tmp/mysql.sock) no such file or directory - :enoent`

I understand that this means it can't find a `/tmp/mysql.sock` socket, however I cannot figure out how to fix this error, or why it even is an error, considering ExpressJS can access the server (using the npm package `mysql`).

Comment: Most likely it’s this: https://serverfault.com/a/478424

Comment: That said, specify `host: "127.0.0.1"` in your connection string explicitly.

Comment: I too would say that the host needs to be specified.